Solve this linear system without explicitly inverting the matrix
I have a general system of linear equations which looks as follows:
$$\left(1-\frac{\hat{A}}{8}-\frac{3\hat{A}}{8}\left(1+\frac{\hat{A}}{6}\right)^{-1}\left(1-\frac{\hat{A}}{6}\right)\right)X=B$$
Where $\hat{A}$ is a square matrix, $X,B$ are column vectors.
This is a part of an implicit linear solver I'm developing.
I would like to know if it's possible to find $X$ without explicitly inverting the matrix $1+\frac{\hat{A}}{6}$, which is something I don't want to do. I would like the algorithm to require only solving linear systems and matrix-vector multiplication.
The only way I see so far is iterative methods.

@Servaes, yes, I always write it as 1, because it's usually clear from the context

I'll write $A:=\hat{A}$ for simplicity, and assume that a solution $X$ exists. Multiply everything by $I+\frac{A}{6}$ to get
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(I+\frac{A}{6}\right)B
&=&\left(I+\frac{A}{6}\right)\left(I-\frac{\hat{A}}{8}-\frac{3\hat{A}}{8}\left(I+\frac{\hat{A}}{6}\right)^{-1}\left(I-\frac{\hat{A}}{6}\right)\right)X\\
&=&\left(\left(I+\frac{A}{6}\right)\left(I-\frac{A}{8}\right)-\frac{3A}{8}\left(I-\frac{A}{6}\right)\right)X\\
&=&\left(I-\frac{A}{3}+\frac{A^2}{24}\right)X.
\end{eqnarray}
Now if $I-\tfrac A3+\tfrac{A^2}{24}$ is invertible then
\begin{eqnarray}
X&=&\left(I-\frac A3+\frac{A^2}{24}\right)^{-1}\left(I+\frac{A}{6}\right)B\\
&=&\left(24I-8A+A^2\right)^{-1}\left(24I+4A\right)B,
\end{eqnarray}
for which you do not need to explicitly invert the matrix $I+\tfrac A6$.

Thanks you, this is exactly what I wanted

@YuriyS Glad to hear that. Please do double-check the algebra, I'm a number theorist not a calculator.

Just to be sure, you used the fact that any matrix commutes with itself and with identity matrix?

Yes, and of course the assumption that $24I-8A+A^2$ is invertible.

And the algebra is correct as far as I checked

Can I expand $\left(I-\frac{A}{3}+\frac{A^2}{24}\right)=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{A}{2}-2-i \sqrt{2}\right)\left(\frac{A}{2}-2+i \sqrt{2}\right)$? This is a correct expansion and would allow me to avoid squaring the matrix.

Sure. You'd still have to multiply those two matrices together though, so I'm not sure how that would be an improvement.

I'll just solve two linear systems instead
